# Creating Em waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Is it necessary for creation of em waves be from same source.

If a positive charge particle and negative charge particle is accelerating with same acceleration will the em waves created be identical in all aspects?

Comment: Classical electrodynamics predicts a positive answer, except the sign of the wave will be dependent on the particle charge, naturally. There is no term in Maxwell equations that takes into account the particle's properties other than charge.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of an EM wave as a transverse disturbance introduced into a preexisting radial electric field (accompanied by a magnetic field).  If you had identical  positive and negative charges oscillating side by side, the two waves would be out of phase. They cancel each other and you have no wave from a net zero charge.

Answer (score -2):

> If a positive charge particle and negative charge particle is accelerating with same acceleration will the em waves created be identical in all aspects?

Just for the record, your statement is true only for a charge and its anti-particle. To show that this is the case, one has to imagine that the acceleration of an electron requires less energy than the acceleration of the heavier proton. So when the electron and the proton are accelerated at the same speed, they release different amounts of energy.

dominecf commented: “There is no term in Maxwell equations that takes into account the particle's properties other than charge.” But there is the photon spin, which for reasons of symmetry needs a closer look.

Maxwell equations take into account the empirical fact that the direction of propagation, the electric and the magnetic field are direction-dependent. If for example the thumb points into the direction of propagation and the second finger in the direction of the electric field at one moment, you have to take the right hand to point with the third finger into the direction of the magnetic field at that moment. This dependency is measurable for radio waves.

Radio waves are generated from accelerated electrons. Until now radio waves from protons or positrons are not generated nor measured. It is a speculation that these particles during acceleration emit left handed EM waves.

Just for the record 2. R.W. Bird wrote, “If you had identical positive and negative charges oscillating side by side, the two waves would be out of phase. They cancel each other and you have no wave from a net zero charge.” is misleading. Once emited, EM waves are not canceling out like water waves. For water, the energy gets dissipated into heat. For EM waves that is not the case. Observable is the undisturbed crossing of both Eam waves.